# passing unicode string from C# exe to C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, unicode

Using this function in my C# exe, I try to pass a Unicode string to my C++ DLL:

```
    [DllImport("Test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int xSetTestString(StringBuilder xmlSettings);
```

This is the function on the C++ DLL side:

__declspec(dllexport) int xSetTestString(char* pSettingsXML);

Before calling the function in C#, I do a MessageBox.Show(string) and it displays all characters properly.  On the C++ side, I do: OutputDebugStringW((wchar_t*)pString);, but that shows that the non-ASCII characters were replaced by '?'.

Comment: What encoding is `pSettingsXML` expected to be?

Comment: Shouldn't your C++ function use `wchar_t*` instead of `char*` if it accepts Unicode?

Comment: Not necessarily.  It could be using UTF-8.

Comment: pSettings is expected to be UTF-16, which is what I believe Microsoft uses internally (not sure if that is correct)

Comment: If it's UTF-16, I agree with @Johannes.  It probably should be `wchar_t`, which is 16-bit on Windows.

Comment: Where are you reading `OutputDebugStringW`'s output? that is where ?'s could appear. Try writing what you receive on the C++ side to a file.

Comment: Thanks Anton!  That was the problem, DbgView didn't display my unicode string properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your export in native DLL to:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int xSetTestString(wchar_t* pSettingsXML);
```

This will do the trick.

BTW - You cant simply do `char* str1 = (wchar_t*)pSettingsXML;` because it does not convert the string. You need to use `wcstombs_s` to convert from `wchar_t*` to `char*`. But in your case you don't have to do it.

**Notes:** Best practice IMO is to use `TCHAR*` instead of `wchar_t*` directly, and set your native dll project *General* option *Character Set* to *Use Unicode Character Set*. This defines `TCHAR*` as `wchar_t*`.

Mirosoft natively uses two sets of functions: ANSI, using 1-byte chracter, marked as FunctionNameA and Unicode, using 2-bytes character, marked as FunctionNameW. This Unicode is in fact UTF-16.

UTF-8 is a multi-byte string that uses 1-byte for standard character and 2-bytes for non-standard characters. To convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 you can use `MultiByteToWideChar` function.

Comment: Why bother with the `TCHAR` stuff? That's just a macro which was introduced decades ago to facilitate the transition to Unicode. New code, even in C++, should start with Unicode.

Comment: Why do Windows programmers bother with FunctionA and FunctionW exports even in latest OS versions, since 'New code, even in C++, should start with Unicode'? Take a look a the StackOverflow. How many q&as involve char* and how many wchar_t*?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[DllImport("Test.dll")]
[return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
private static extern int externalTestString(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType. // The string type the C uses ansi/unicode/...) ] String st
    );

public int TestString(String st // or string builder here)
{
     // Perform input/output checks here + exception handling
}
```

Make sure the C++ functions are visible outside the DLL (using __declspec dllexport).
Check using depends (comes with VS2005) if you can see the functions and what there name is.

If your C++ functions are NOT within classes, then you can use unmangled names if you use extern "C", if they are in classes, you will need to specify an entry point with the mangled names from depends.

Comment: I tried this but same problem:

        [DllImport("Test.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public static extern int xSetTestString(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String xmlSettings);

Comment: What type is your C++ string? char* wchar_t*, std::string,... ?